# executing exec in cakephp for ffmpeg not converting video

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to run this in cakephp

```
function test()
{       
   $mainDirectoryPath = WWW_ROOT . "media";                        
   $filePath = "userId_10/vid_1444387525.mp4";                  

   $newPath = "userId_10/Output.mp4";                  
   $value = exec("ffmpeg -i  $filePath -s 320x320 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k $newPath");        
   $this->jsonOutput($value);

}
```

i am getting nothing $value is empty,
however in shell if i run this as shell_exec() in a php file it works. 
what is wrong above

UPDATE:

Ok now i have created a file with following code

```
<?php

 $mainFile = $_REQUEST['mainFile'];
 $newPath = $_REQUEST['newFile'];

 echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i  $mainFile -s 320x320 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k $newPath");   
 @unlink($mainFile);

?>
```

If i run this with mainFile and newFile it works.

However when i run it in function as

```
   $val = "php video.php?mainFile=$filePath&newFile=$newPath > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
       exec($val);
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: may be this will help you `exec("ffmpeg cmd", $output, $return_var);`

Comment: @VipinSharma whats output and returnvar

Comment: Please check  link >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449825/what-is-the-php-exec-return-value or http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: are you sure filePath and newPath is correct ?

Comment: @VipinSharma check the update,

Answer (score 0):

Check `php.ini` file and disable_functions have not `exec` comamnd.
For security reason site admin  disabled `exec` command in `php.ini`.
Remove `exec` from disable_functions  in `php.ini` file.